# Python: Getting "internalServerError:500" while trying to use requests.post

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Getting the "internalServerError" while using the requests.post method, and the same data, header, URL is working through Postman.

In the headers, I'm using Authorization, Content-Type.and the data is in JSON.

```
r = requests.post (url,headers=headers,data=data)

> <Response [500]> {"message":"error.internalServerError","description":"Internal server error","fieldErrors":null}
```

Comment: Are you expecting a 200?  Are you running the code on the same machine as Postman?  Check your character encodings and escapes.

Comment: `import json` and try: `r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))`

Comment: Thanks @jignatius. it's working. But why we need this, we are already indicating JSON in 'Content-Type'

Comment: We need to import json because you are using the function json.dumps() . Suppose in some code there are two json objects available to python, and you dont write import, then python will have no option of knowing which one to choose. That's why you need to import the python object by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a *dictionary* to the `data` parameter the data will automatically be **form-encoded** when the request is made.

However, according to the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

> There are times that you may want to send data that is not
> form-encoded. If you pass in a *string* instead of a dict, that data
> will be posted **directly**.

and:

> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly
> using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be
> encoded automatically

So you could also write:

```
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
```